# How can I release memory usage in apache camel?

Tags: java, apache-camel

all.
I am starter for camel.
I have some problem.

I have one route for inserting to table by using sql.
This route is triggered with timer component.

I want to insert 20k record. So the value of repeatCount set 20000.

After all processing is done, I checked memory usage. But memory was maintained at a high utilization rate.

I knew that all memory used would be initialized once an event was processed.

During processing, memory utilization increased continuously and processing ended, but memory utilization did not fall.

Why does this happen?

**Router File**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<routes id="TestRoutes" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
    <route id="testRoute1">
        <from id="_from1" uri="timer://timer1?period=1&amp;repeatCount=200000"/>
  <setBody>
   <constant>TEST Data!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!</constant>
  </setBody>
  <to uri="sql:INSERT INTO temp_test(test1) VALUES(:#${body})"/>
    </route>
</routes>
```

Answer (score 0):

The best practices with such amount of data to process is to batch SQL statements.

Instead of processing the 20k records all at once, split them into small chucks (batchs).

For example, if:

```
 BATCH_SIZE = 100
```

Then you will have to process `20` batches since all records count is `20000`

You need to define an `AggregationStrategy' for your SQL statements and. This aggregation strategy will be use by the aggregate() method.

You will also need a "*batchSizePredicate*" that uses camel `Predicate` to filter statement according to the batch size. Finally, this one will be used by `completionPredicate()`.

All this features would give a route like this one :

```
from("quartz2://myGroup/myTimerTransaction?cron=0+1+0+*+*+?")
.bean(QueryTool.class, "performQuery")
.to("direct:database-save");

from("direct:database-save")
                .log("Start saving to database ....")
                .aggregate(constant(true), batchAggregationStrategy())
                .completionPredicate(batchSizePredicate())
                .completionTimeout(BATCH_TIME_OUT)
                .bean(persistService)
                .log("End saving to database ....")
                .end();
```

you must also define a `completionTimeout` that tells what the arbitrary time to complete a batch aggregation.

I would also create a `QueryTool.java` class that would perform the SQL with a JDBC queries.

Here is a [general example](https://github.com/SourceAlliesBlog/LogToDatabaseMapper) to give you a concrete demonstration

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I have another question. Is the fetched data in memory disappear in memory when end point in route? I wonder that when exchange and aggregating data is released in memory.

Comment: Memory footprints are done when a processing is currently done. So, your route won't end until all batches are processed.

Splitting and doing that processing in small chucks only reduce the memory footprints to ease the JVM. If you want to speed up your processing you have to add parrallel streams to your routes.

Comment: I edited the answer to add a code sample for a similar issue.